how to increase touch box of a button and make background stay the same?
I have encountered into a problem where my image was too big on a button so I had to decrease my buttons size that also decreased the touch box or so called hitbox.
what I want is the background to remain the same size but to increase the touchbox.

If you just want extra hitbox, you may set padding attribute as much as you want.

does not work, the code is this:




If you just need clickable thing with image in it, then use ImageView with app:srcCompat set as drawable you want. Then set background attribute to ?attr/selectableItemBackground for ripple effect on touch.

I don't need a clickable thing with image its the same thing that I am using, a button that has a background of xml that has vector code with path data in it.

But see, if you set background to button, I mean it is just clickable thing! In that case, component does not have to be Button. Use ImageView and set click action with setOnClickListener. Background is not affected by padding, but srcCompat of ImageView indeed is.

got it working with the imageView you were right thanks. another question, when i press the imageview there is shadow alike animation, is there any way to remove that?

Glad to hear! But next time, keep in mind that posting with your code and explaining current situation, what you have tried, image or drawing of desired outputs could lead to more answers.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

i just changed the button to image button like this

and because i am using vector layout with pathdata i decreased the width and higth there so my X(for back button) appeared smaller and increased the size of the image button
